# How to put views under another folder in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a view template that is currently `FooBundle:Bar:baz.html.twig`. However, since I have pretty many templates, I'd like to organize and put them in folders like `Resources\Views\Bar\sub\baz.html.twig`. I tried using `FooBundle:Bar:sub:baz.html.twig` without success.

Is there a way to put view files one more folder deeper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
FooBundle:Bar:sub/baz.html.twig
```

Where

- `FooBundle` refers to the bundle;
- `Bar` refers to the controller;
- `sub/baz.html.twig` is the path to file (from the `Resources/Views/Bar/` folder);